# TFS Get Latest Version History

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops

I know we can get the change set history from TFS easily but i want to get the history of 'get latest version' request from TFS.

So my question is that is there any way to see a log of who and when any of the team member made a 'get latest version' request on TFS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this on Visual Studio Team Services (was Team Foundation Service).

If you describe what you are trying to achieve then maybe there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

TFS keeps a command log that keeps track of this, but I believe it only keeps the last 7 days of commands.  I know some teams setup a SQL job that exports the command log every few days so they can keep more than 7 days of history.

You can see the Command log by going to the URL: http:/tfsserver:port/tfs/_oi

You can also query the SQL table tbl_Command, although this is not officially supported.

Comment: where would i find the port number?

Comment: Just go to your typical TFS Web Access site, and add _oi onto the end.  You can find the link to the Web Portal from within team explorer in Visual Studio if you don't know it.  By default the port is 8080

Comment: if my tfs site is `https://abcd.visualstudio.com/` than can you please tell me where should i add `_oi` because when i append it like `https://abcd.visualstudio.com/_oi` it gives `page not found`

Comment: OI is only supported on TFS where you have ownership of the instance. On VSO you have no access to OI or the database table mentioned above.

Comment: MrHinsh is right, I didn't notice that you were using VSO.